# Coditioning in python loops

Tags: python, loops, screen, screenshot, pyautogui

```
import time
import pyautogui


location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ok.png')

pyautogui.click(location)
```

HOW DO I WRITE THE FOLLOWING STATEMENT AS CODE?

**If image is no found on screen, keep running `location` until the image is found.**

otherwise the code is terminating immediately.

I tried :

```
While location == None : #Or location == False
    pyautogui.click(location)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `while` like this:

```
while location is not None:
    pyautogui.click(location)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Pyautogui documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html?highlight=locateOnScreen#the-locate-functions):

> If the image can’t be found on the screen, `locateOnScreen()` raises `ImageNotFoundException`

This means that you have to handle the error message in order to keep the program running in case the image is not there.
Try using exception handling:

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    # Try to do this
    try:
        location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ok.png')
        # Location found with no errors: break the while loop and proceed
        break
    # If an error has occurred (image not found), keep waiting
    except:
        pass

pyautogui.click(location)
```

**NOTE:** This generates an infinite loop until the image is found on screen. To break this loop and stop the script execution use CTRL+C on the Shell.

In alternative you may set a maximum time waiting for the image:

```
import time
import pyautogui

max_wait = 30 # Seconds
end = time.time() + max_wait

while time.time() <= end:
    # Try to do this
    try:
        location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ok.png')
        # Location found with no errors: break the while loop and proceed
        break
    # If an error has occurred (image not found), keep waiting
    except:
        pass    
    
pyautogui.click(location)
```